# Android project most code shows red but when i run it , it works

Tags: android

all of sudden my mainactivty most of the codes have turned highlight red, this normally happens when error accurs  also i see the zigzag lines on tab , but when i run the app it runs without no errors ? whats wrong

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import static testtt.myapplication.Constants.FIFTH_COLUMN;
import static testtt.myapplication.Constants.FIRST_COLUMN;
import static testtt.myapplication.Constants.FOURTH_COLUMN;
import static testtt.myapplication.Constants.SECOND_COLUMN;
import static testtt.myapplication.Constants.THIRD_COLUMN;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
    public int count = 0;
    public String temp;
    private Document htmlDocument;

    private TextView parsedHtmlNode;
    private TextView textViewwww;
    private String htmlContentInStringFormat;
    private String dayys;
    private String amarrdatta;
    private String duhr_val1;
    private String asr_val1;
    private String maghreb_val1;
    private String isha_val1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        parsedHtmlNode = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.html_content);
        textViewwww = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2Activity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        Button htmlTitleButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        htmlTitleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               JsoupAsyncTask jsoupAsyncTask = new JsoupAsyncTask();
                jsoupAsyncTask.execute();


            }
        });
    }
    @Override
```

i posted most of the code red line shows on

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private Document htmlDocument;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        parsedHtmlNode = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.html_content);
        textViewwww = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

tried clean even rebuild even closed it dont turn black

Comment: public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {     MainActivity is greyed out ????????????????

Comment: Something wrong with your IDE. If it's eclipse, then clean, restart, remove all errors from Problems tab. Vote to close, because it's too broad and impossible to fix your IDE issue with this information.